Disappering gauge field information after double KK reduction
Consider a general metric on a 3+1 dimensional space on a $\mathbb{T}^2$ torus $S_\theta^1\times S_\phi^1$ with compact coordinates $\theta\sim\theta+2\pi,\phi\sim\phi+2\pi$:
$$ds^2 = G_{tt}dt^2+G_{rr}dr^2+G_{\theta t}d\theta dt+G_{\theta\theta}d\theta^2+G_{\theta \phi}d\theta d\phi+G_{\phi t}d\phi dt+G_{\phi \phi}d\phi^2.$$
The metric contains a temporal part denoted by the coordinate $t$ and radial part denoted by $r$.
Now consider a first KK reduction with respect to $S^1_\phi$ circle, as consequence the metric is reduced to describe 2+1 dimensional system with extra abelian gauge field $A$ and scalar field $\xi$ known as the radion, such that according to Kaluza-Klein mechanism:
$$e^{2\xi}=G_{\phi\phi}$$
$$A=\frac{G_{\theta\phi}}{G_{\phi\phi}}d\theta+\frac{G_{t\phi}}{G_{\phi\phi}}dt$$
$$g_{\mu\nu}=G_{\mu\nu}-e^{2\xi}A_{\mu}A_{\nu},\quad {\mu,\nu}\in{r,t,\theta}$$
with $g_{\mu\nu}$ the reduced 2+1 dimensional metric.
Now we take the 2+1 dimensional system and make another KK reduction with respect to the $S_{\theta}^1$ circle, as consequence we will end with 1+1 dimensional system containing a new gauge field $\tilde{A}$ and a new radion $\sigma$ such that:
$$e^{2\sigma} = g_{\theta\theta}$$
$$\tilde{A}=\frac{g_{\theta t}}{g_{\theta\theta}}dt$$
$$m_{\mu\nu} = g_{\mu\nu}-e^{2\sigma}\tilde{A}_{\mu}\tilde{A}_{\nu},\quad {\mu,\nu}\in{r,t}$$
with $m_{\mu\nu}$ the reduced 1+1 dimensional metric.
However, what happened to the extra fields of the 2+1 dimensional system $A$ and $\xi$?
For $\xi$, it seems that there is no change at all and it constitute another scalar field in addition to $\sigma$, but for $A$ containing a component in the $\theta$ direction it seems that it either disappear completely from the theory, which sound peculiar to me, or becomes another scalar field which we denote by $\eta$:
$$e^{2\eta}=A_{\theta}.$$
However I didn't see any source which denote this kind of scalar field, its name, and how it enters the reduced the Hilbert action.

Comments to the post (v3): 1. Yes, $A_{\theta}$ becomes another scalar field. 2. The radial part $A_r$ seems to be missing in $A$. 3. Similar for $G_{rt}$, $G_{r\theta}$, $G_{r\phi}$.

@Qmechanic the radial part is not exists in $A$ since we choose a setup in which $G_{r\phi} = 0$
